# Can't send/receive command over serial to Arduino to control LED

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, serial-port

I have been working on a little side project in which I want to control my Arduino pins via UI that was designed in Tkinter.

[image: UI screenshot]

The UI is set to send serial command to my Arduino that will place that particular PIN high and turn on the LED for example.

The problem that I am facing is that when I check one of my pins, for instance, PIN4 and press 'SET', a routine is called which keep the PIN high for a small duration of time before putting the PIN to low again. I have notice that this happens when multiple USBs are connected to my laptop. If I remove all USB devices except Arduino and then run my sript then the program works flawlessly as expected.

My intention is to simply connect my arduino to my laptop while the scipt automatically connects the appropriate COM port.

Could someone help me understand where I am making a mistake in my script.

Thanks

Here is the link to the code: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/28PJ

Comment: Oh no. I dont know how did that happened. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Please don't link to code on other sites. Reduce your code to the absolute minimum that will reproduce the problem and include it in your question.

Comment: @BryanOakley, that's why I am here for help because I seem to not understand what the problem is. Thanks

Comment: Usama: the process of reducing the problem down is a technique for you to learn. Remove a line of code, test, remove a line of code, test, until you can't remove any more lines but you still have a problem. This is how you learn to debug software.  The process will help you understand whether it's related to the GUI code, or the serial port code, or something else.